# Vectorized count of daily longest consecutive streak

Tags: python, pandas

For evaluating daily longest consecutive runtimes of a power plant, I have to evaluate the longest streak **per day**, meaning that each day is considered as a separate timeframe.

So let's say I've got the power output in the dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.Series(
    data=[
        *np.zeros(4), *(np.full(24*5, 19.5) + np.random.rand(24*5)), 
        *np.zeros(4), *(np.full(8, 19.5) + np.random.rand(8)), 
        *np.zeros(5), *(np.full(24, 19.5) + np.random.rand(24)), 
        *np.zeros(27), *(np.full(24, 19.5) + np.random.rand(24))], 
    index=pd.date_range(start='2019-07-01 00:00:00', periods=9*24, freq='1h'))
```

And the "cutoff-power" is `1` (everything below that is considered as off). I use this to mask the "on"-values, shift and compare the mask to itself to count the number of consecutive `groups`. Finally I group the `groups` by the *days of the year* in the index and count the daily consecutive values `consec_group`:

```
mask = df > 1
groups = mask.ne(mask.shift()).cumsum()
consec_group = groups[mask].groupby(groups[mask].index.date).value_counts()
```

Which yields:

```
consec_group
Out[3]: 
2019-07-01  2    20
2019-07-02  2    24
2019-07-03  2    24
2019-07-04  2    24
2019-07-05  2    24
2019-07-06  4     8
            2     4
            6     3
2019-07-07  6    21
2019-07-09  8    24
dtype: int64
```

But I'd like to have the **maximum value** of each consecutive daily streak and dates without any runtime should be displayed with zeros, as in `2019-07-08  7    0`. See the expected result:

```
2019-07-01    20
2019-07-02    24
2019-07-03    24
2019-07-04    24
2019-07-05    24
2019-07-06     8
2019-07-07    21
2019-07-08     0
2019-07-09    24
dtype: int64
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove second level by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), filter out second duplicated values by call back with [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) - it working, because `.value_counts` sort `Series`:

```
consec_group = (consec_group.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)[lambda x: ~x.index.duplicated()]
                            .asfreq('d', fill_value=0))
print (consec_group)
```

Or solution with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
consec_group = (consec_group.groupby(level=0)
                            .first() 
                            .asfreq('d', fill_value=0))
```

---

```
print (consec_group)
2019-07-01    20
2019-07-02    24
2019-07-03    24
2019-07-04    24
2019-07-05    24
2019-07-06     8
2019-07-07    21
2019-07-08     0
2019-07-09    24
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I really like the idea of using the existing sort provide by value_counts instead of using max again. :) +1

Comment: Yep, me too. Thanks and great solution! I didn't know that `value_counts()` will always sort in descending order, but the pandas docs say so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess I was too close to the finish line to see the answer... Looks like I had already solved the complex part.
So right after posting the question, I tested `max` with the `level=0` argument instead of `level=1` and that was the solution:

```
max_consec_group = consec_group.max(level=0).asfreq('d', fill_value=0)
```

Thanks at jezrael for the `asfreq` part!

Comment: I was on this exact same path.